# Persistent Gtk.TreeIters

Tags: c#, gtk#

Ok, so Gtk.TreeStore has a field flags, of type Gtk.TreeModelFlags.
One of those values is Gtk.TreeModelFlags.ItersPersist
I would like to create a TreeStore with that flag set (for obvious reasons), but the flag is read-only, and I can see no other way of getting persistent iterators.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change that flag when implementing the `Gtk.TreeModel` interface in your own class. In that case, you can implement your iterators any way you like, and so you can make them persist.

That said, I don't think the reasons are that obvious why you would want persistent iterators. I think they are non-persistent for performance reasons, and if you want a persistent reference to a position in the tree, you can use `Gtk.TreePath`.